# Why is T-SQL Returning Duplicate Rows, Join Issue I Believe

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code as written below returns the appropriate customers, lockers, units and balance. However, when I add in the commented-out code it reiterates each customer's data for each club even though each customer can only be a member of one club.

```
USE db1
GO

SELECT [db1].[dbo].[Customer].[CustomerNumber] AS 'Customer No.'
--  ,A. ClubID AS 'Club ID No.'
,(SELECT CONCAT (SI.Locker, '-', SI.Frequency)) AS Locker
,SI.Unit AS Unit
--,[db2].[dbo].[vueClub].Club_aka AS Club
,[db1].[dbo].[Customer_Balance].[CurrentBalance]

FROM [db1].[dbo].[Customer_Balance]
JOIN [db1].[dbo].[Customer]
    ON [db1].[dbo].[Customer_Balance].POSCusNo = Customer.CustomerNumber
    JOIN [SQLSrv01].[ db3].[dbo].[md_Table_1] AS D
    ON D.Contract_no = [db1].[dbo].[Customer_Balance]. POSCusNo
    JOIN [SQLSrv01].[ db2].[dbo].[vueSoldLockers] AS SI
    ON SI.CustomerID = [db1].[dbo].[Customer].CustomerID
    --JOIN [db2].[dbo].[vueClub] AS A
    --ON [db1].[dbo].[Customer].SiteID = A.SiteID
WHERE [db1].[dbo].[Customer_Balance].StatusCode = '1234'
ORDER BY Customer.CustomerNumber ASC
```

So if I run it as is I get:

```
Customer No.    Locker  Unit    Current Balance
1               315     A1      456.00
2               316     A3      1204.70
3               317     B2      335.60
4               318     B4      1500.30
```

But if I include the commented-out code I get:

```
Customer No. Club ID No Locker  Unit    Club    Current Balance
1            4          315     A1      Tigers  456.00
1            3          315     A1      Lions   456.00
2            4          316     A3      Tigers  1204.70
2            3          316     A3      Lions   1204.70
3            4          317     B2      Tigers  335.60
3            3          317     B2      Lions   335.60
4            4          318     B4      Tigers  1500.30
4            3          318     B4      Lions   1500.30
```

Is it because I don't have the JOIN set up properly?

Comment: What are the keys (primary and foreign) of table Customer and vueClub?  It appears you may be joining on an incomplete key and as others pointed out, vueclub has multiple clubs for a SITE.  Perhaps you need to be joining on more than SITE?  Since site is a 1:M with club and user appears to be 1:1 with site you get a 1:M between customer and site which is why you have repeated records.  To resolve, you'd need to join on the complete key. Provide the DDL for Customer and VueClub.  DB relationships are like those in life; you better understand stand them, or get burnt by them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Customer No. Club ID No Locker  Unit    Club    Current Balance
1            4          315     A1      Tigers  456.00
1            3          315     A1      Lions   456.00
```

You are joining customer to vueClub on SiteID. Looks like  the site customer 1 is in, has 2 clubs (3, 4)